# How to get only Text within the div, rather concerning about any internal tags in TestCafe

Tags: testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, testcafe, ui-testing

I need only the text **Gaps in Care**,
Took selector as **div.patient-contact-popup li.nav-item a** , it results as **Gaps in Care1**.
How/What will be selector, to get only the text portion not any numeric because it is dynamically changed.

[Please refer the attached screenshot, for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFRj9.png)

Comment: Which one did you use Selector.innerText or Selector.textContent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) DOM property and TestCafe [`ClientFunction`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client) API to achieve the required behavior. The following test example demonstrates this approach:

```js
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `My fixture`
    .page `https://b22yw.csb.app/`;

test('Check navlink text', async t => {
    const navLink = Selector('.nav-link');

    const getNavLinkText = ClientFunction(() => navLink().childNodes[0].textContent.trim(), {
        dependencies: { navLink }
    });

    await t.expect(getNavLinkText()).eql('Gaps in Care');
});
```